# AzureAD b2c MSAL - Token response is missing the access token

Tags: swift, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm experiencing problem(s) while attempting to authenticate a user using Azure’s active directory b2c in swift. It *appears* that I'm able to login successfully in the webview. AD is able to find my user and will return error if the password is wrong, but After I 'login' I'm redirected to my app with the following error:

Could not acquire token: Error Domain=MSALErrorDomainCode=-41205"null"
Userinfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Token response is missing the access token}

```
let kSignupOrSigninPolicy = "b2c_1_signupandsignin" // Your signup and sign-in policy you created in the portal
let kScopes: [String] = [""]
let kEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/%@/%@"
let kTenantName = "sampleapp.onmicrosoft.com" // Your tenant name




@IBAction func authorizationButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let kAuthority = String(format: kEndpoint, kTenantName, kSignupOrSigninPolicy)


    do {
        let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication.init(clientId: kClientID, authority: kAuthority)
        application.acquireToken(forScopes: kScopes) { (result, error) in
                if  error == nil {
                    self.accessToken = (result?.accessToken)!
                    self.loggingText.text = "Access token is \(self.accessToken)"
                    self.signoutButton.isEnabled = true;
                    self.callGraphApiButton.isEnabled = true;
                    self.editProfileButton.isEnabled = true;
                    self.refreshTokenButton.isEnabled = true;


                } else {
                    self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token: \(error ?? "No error informarion" as! Error)"
                }
        }
    } catch {
        self.loggingText.text = "Unable to create application \(error)"
    }
}
```

I suspect something is wrong with either the scope configuration on the backend of how I'm listing the scope on the frontend. As far as I can tell we have no custom scope configuration on the backend. I've tried a handful of different strings for the kScopes variable:

```
"openid"
""
"https://graph.windows.net/openid"
"https://graph.windows.com/openid"
"https://graph.microsoft.com/openid"
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the places where it's helpful to take a look is our public [MSALError class](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/blob/dev/MSAL/src/public/MSALError.h). It often helps debug issues like these.

### B2C Does Not Currently Support Microsoft Graph

The problem you are running in to is you are requesting access and scopes to Microsoft's Graph API. **Microsoft's Graph API isn't supported to be accessed with a B2C tenant yet.**

B2C is meant to give you an access token that you can use against your own backend Web API, along with scopes that you wish passed to that service to limit access to that service. Without a backend service to access, you will not get an access_token.

This is referenced in the documentation in the Sample:

`let kGraphURI = "<Your backend API>" // This is your backend API that you've configured to accept your app's tokens
    let kScopes: [String] = ["<Your backend API>/demo.read"] // This is a scope that you've configured your backend API to look for.`

It makes sense if you think about it - B2C is Business to Consumer. Our use case is that you would want to use an identity system that you own and control for your consumers. In this scenario, you'll most likely be offering customers an actual service that you'll want to restrict access to (which is the point of an identity system). This is true even if they sign in with Google or Facebook (which our product supports) since you'll then want to tell your backend service the user identity to either create an account for them or give them access to your service.

The exact error you are getting is that you are requesting access to the Microsoft Graph API, which is not possible and therefore can't be consented to. The B2C service knows this and returns a response without an access_token. Our MSAL library is reporting back to you that this is the case, and that authorization failed.

### But I do want to use the Microsoft Graph API with my own identity system!

That's an interesting use case, and as the Microsoft Graph grows we see this as an ask more and more. We're working to enhance B2C to support this in the future. Always check the GitHub homepage and release notes to see when this has been added.

If you want to allow a user to use the Microsoft Graph API only, you should leverage the generic MSAL SDKs and onboard an application with https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.

### But I want to just sign someone in, not access any API at all!

This may be the case with you, since you're trying to access the Microsoft Graph but appear to be doing nothing with it.

There are two parts to Signing someone in:

*OpenID Connect (Authentication)* - The identity system tells you that *yes, this user exists in our system* and that is all. This is usually represented by handing you an id_token. No access to anything is given. This could be useful if you just want to check that a user is legitimate before on boarding to your own identity system.

*OAuth2 (Authorization)* - You ask the identity system to give you access to a resource it controls. This access is given to you to hand off to the resource by giving you an access token. You do need to provide an identity to the identity system to see if the user should have access to the resource, but that isn't necessarily using OpenID Connect, and it may not even be a human! (like with Service to Service connections that use API keys / client secrets which are just text strings)

Most developers use both OpenID Connect and OAuth2 as they want to sign someone in and then access a resource. For instance, a normal flow to the Microsoft Graph API works like this. You want a user to sign in (with a Microsoft Account) and then access the Graph API (using that Microsoft Account).

As I said though, sometimes you just want the identity system to say the user exists and that's all.

We have a flow to do that, [which is discussed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc). In short, you'll want to change your scope to `&scope=openid%20offline_access` but you should absolutely read that document and make sure you understand the scenario fully.

Comment: To add to this answer, Azure AD B2C does support the Azure AD Graph API (graph.windows.net).  [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) a great doc that shows you how to construct requests and get tokens for the Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Thanks! that's really good information and definitely clarifies what a lot of grey areas. The problem is that that was one of the first scopes I tried to use. It definitely makes the most sense. But when I use that scope I get this error: '4200 openid,offline_acess are reserved scopes and may not be specified in the acquire token call.' This makes me think that the framework is expecting the scopes somewhere else. I tried using the slice parameters to add scope parameter manually and I get my error 'token response is missing the access token'

Comment: @7sharp9 - No I switched to this sample project: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-native-nxoauth2-v2 which uses this library https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client plugged in my configuration strings and it just worked. I still have no idea what the problem was with this library.